# Best practice for JSON deserialization

Tags: flutter, dart, cross-platform

I have two different endpoints.

"/api/users?page=1" with the response below :

```
{"users": [{"id":1, "name": "David"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Richard"}]}
```

"/api/pictures?page=2" with this response :

```
{"pictures": [{"userID": 1, "urls": ["https://b.co/c.png", "https://a.com/b.png"]}]}
```

What is the best solution to merge this two endpoints in OOP.

```
class User {
    final int id;
    final String name;

    User(this.id, this.name);
}

class Picture {
    final User user;
    final List<String> pictures;

    Picture(this.user, this.pictures);

    factory Picture.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        return Picture(
             // Here I have to find json['userID'] from previously fetched users. I can use singletons but its an anti-pattern and not preferred.
             , json['urls']
        );
    }
}
```

I'm not gonna change my server responses. please help me out.

Comment: You wan't to merge the two responses into one object?

Comment: @croxx5f yup. That's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I would `await` for both API returns and then have it be passed inside `Picture` class. Also, I would implement `fromJson` on `User` class too

```
class User {
    final int id;
    final String name;

    User(this.id, this.name);
    
    User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic>) {
      // .....
    }
}

class Picture {
    final User user;
    final List<String> pictures;

    Picture(this.user, this.pictures);

    factory Picture.fromJson({
      Map<String, dynamic> pictureJson, 
      Map<String, dynamic> userJson
     }) {
        final user = User.fromJson(userJson);

        return Picture(
             user: user;
             // Here I have to find json['userID'] from previously fetched users. I can use singletons but its an anti-pattern and not preferred.
             
             , json['urls']
        );
    }
}
```